# ClassCastException encountered in a Unit Test using Mockito to stub a Stream API "map()" method

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

I'm attempting to perform a unit test on a service layer method within a Spring Boot application that simply retrieves all entities inside the database. I'm using Stream API to map all entities retrieved using `ListCrudRepository`  method `findAll()` and convert each entity into a DTO. I created a mapper class to be invoked inside the `.map()` of the stream.

```
@Service
public class ContentDTOMapper implements Function\<Content, ContentDTO\> {

    @Override
    public ContentDTO apply(Content content) {
        return new ContentDTO(
                content.getTitle(),
                content.getDesc(),
                content.getStatus(),
                content.getContentType(),
                content.getDateCreated(),
                content.getDateUpdated(),
                content.getUrl()
        );
    }

}
```

```
public List<ContentDTO> getAllContents() {
        return repository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(contentDTOMapper)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm trying to stub the `getAllContents()` method using Mockito but I'm getting a ClassCastException whenever I try to test the method

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ContentServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks //this annotation creates all available mock objects that can be injected
    //must explicitly use "new" to create the object whose method is to be tested
    ContentServiceImpl contentService = new ContentServiceImpl();
    
    @Mock //creates the mock objects or the "dependent" objects of the class being primarily tested
    ContentRepository contentRepository;
    @Mock
    ContentDTOMapper contentDTOMapper;
    @Mock
    Environment environment;

@Test
void getAllContentsValidTest(){
//given - prepare data
Content content = new Content();
content.setId(1);
content.setTitle("test content title name");
content.setDesc("test content description for a new content");
content.setStatus(Status.PUBLISHED);
content.setContentType(Type.ARTICLE);
content.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
content.setDateUpdated(LocalDateTime.of(2099, Month.DECEMBER, 15,12,12));
content.setUrl("http://test.com");

        Content content2 = new Content();
        content2.setId(2);
        content2.setTitle("test content title name2");
        content2.setDesc("test content description for a new content2");
        content2.setStatus(Status.PUBLISHED);
        content2.setContentType(Type.ARTICLE);
        content2.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        content2.setDateUpdated(LocalDateTime.of(2099, Month.DECEMBER, 15,12,12));
        content2.setUrl("http://test2.com");
    
        ContentDTO contentDTO = new ContentDTO(
                content.getTitle(),
                content.getDesc(),
                content.getStatus(),
                content.getContentType(),
                content.getDateCreated(),
                content.getDateUpdated(),
                content.getUrl()
        );
    
        ContentDTO contentDTO2 = new ContentDTO(
                content2.getTitle(),
                content2.getDesc(),
                content2.getStatus(),
                content2.getContentType(),
                content2.getDateCreated(),
                content2.getDateUpdated(),
                content2.getUrl()
        );
    
    
    
        //when
        List<ContentDTO> contentDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        contentDTOList.add(contentDTO);
        contentDTOList.add(contentDTO2);
    
        Mockito.when(contentRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(contentDTOMapper)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())).thenReturn(contentDTOList);
    
        List<ContentDTO> actual = contentService.getAllContents(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    
        //then
        Assertions.assertEquals(actual,contentDTOList);
    }
```

This is the specific exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class dev.earlpadron.contentcalendar.model.DTO.ContentDTO cannot be cast to class dev.earlpadron.contentcalendar.model.Content (dev.earlpadron.contentcalendar.model.DTO.ContentDTO and dev.earlpadron.contentcalendar.model.Content are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Is this the proper way to unit test `getAllContents()` inside my service class? How do I resolve this issue or how can I write this in a better way?

Comment: You can't mock a deeply-nested call like that: if `contentRepository` is your mocked object, you can only specify the behavior of `contentRepository.findAll()`.

Comment: So I'll have to do this instead `Mockito.when(contentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(contentDTOList);`  

 but in that case how do I properly stub `.findAll()` so it returns a list of type ContentDTO and not of type Content? Or in the other words, how do I stub a stream method?

Comment: I understand now I just used the stream method outside the stubbing call, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the proper way to unit test getAllContents() inside my service class?

If you try to stub the whole content of `getAllContents` it would not really test much since you do not let the method execute anything at all. And besides you should mock simple statements based on mock objects, let's analyze it for a bit

```java
 Mockito.when(contentRepository.findAll() //this is a call to `mock.method()`
                .stream() // this would be a call to real List object so it cannot longer be mocked
                .map(contentDTOMapper) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .thenReturn(contentDTOList);
```

> How do I resolve this issue or how can I write this in a better way?

You should mock only the `mock.method` kind of calls, to make it simpler something like this

```java
 List<Content> repositoryValues = new ArrayList<>();
        repositoryValues.add(content);
        repositoryValues.add(content);
 Mockito.when(contentRepository.findAll())
        .thenReturn(repositoryValues);
```

The code above will give a set of values for the mapper to work with, then the logic inside `getAllContents` will use that preconditions to pass it to the mapper. and return the correctly converted `List<ContentDTO>`.

Finally your test can compare the test generated list against your test prepared `contentDTOList` to verify that the logic works as expected, fulfilling the scope of test (runtime vs known values)

**-- Update look into the test runtime of getAllContents**

During test, if you were to debug the `getAllContents` method it should look something like this

```java
contentRepository.findAll() // returns preconditioned (known) value stubbed in the mock a.k.a "repositoryValues"
                .stream() // This converts the "known" list returned above into a stream of values
                .map(contentDTOMapper) // This will call your mapper providing each value (the ones you setup in your "when" stub), one at a time 
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: When you say "preconditions to pass it to the mapper", do you mean the stubbed method call `Mockito.when(contentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(repositoryValues);`   interally calls `.map()` method automatically converting the initial list of type Content to ContentDTO? Can you expand what you mean by "preconditions"? Thank you for the response!

Comment: Not exactly, `Mockito.when(contentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(repositoryValues);` will return a "known list of records" (repositoryValues), when the `findAll` method is called. Then the execution flow of `getAllContents` will continue, next statement being the `stream()` converting the stubbed list (known precondition) into a stream, and then execution the `map` function over the values in that same stream.